# VPN is blocked only on windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, blocking, pptp

Hi was trying to setup an vpn on my macbook because the network i am on blocks a lot of pages and it worked fine on the macbook i used the afreevpn.com vpn it worked no problems then i tried on my windows computer and it gave me the 807 errorcode so i tried using my mobile bandwidth and personal hotspot and it worked through that so how do i get around this?

I have already tried editing some registry entries like: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent adding nat support

but that didn't help so i am counting on you to help me :)
Thank you for any help in advance
and i am sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Bypassing content restrictions can be a big no-no in many places, that being said, are they both wired, wireless or is one wired and the other wireless? you mention that using your personal wifi and the windows 7 machine it works? if so can you specify that in your post?

Comment: Both devices are wireless